# StoredProcedureQuery don't return anything

Tags: java, sql, jpa, java-stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure to update or insert into database.

UpdateMnoMsisdnStatus.sql :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateMnoMsisdnStatus]
(@Msisdn VARCHAR(20),
@MnoRef VARCHAR(255),
@Status VARCHAR(15)
)
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRAN
BEGIN TRY

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT /* F4BB6573-5C43-498D-8DE7-65610801F925 */ NULL FROM dbo.MsisdnStock WHERE Msisdn = @Msisdn)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Msisdn does not exist in stock', 16, 1)
    END

    IF EXISTS (SELECT /* 61FB92B0-F811-4022-9849-8E51C20291E9 */ NULL FROM dbo.MnoMsisdnStock WHERE Msisdn = @Msisdn AND MnoRef = @MnoRef)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE dbo.MnoMsisdnStock SET /* 9F97046E-F65D-46A2-8D99-61DC56A45A3D */
                Status = @Status ,
                StatusDate = (case when NOT @Status='ToBeRestored' then  GETDATE() end)
    WHERE Msisdn = @Msisdn AND MnoRef = @MnoRef
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO MnoMsisdnStock (Msisdn, MnoRef, Status, StatusDate)
            /* CD15DACD-5097-41BC-B9A7-3AF1F7730D04 */
            VALUES
            (@Msisdn, @MnoRef, @Status, GETDATE())

        END

    UPDATE dbo.MsisdnStock SET /* 6AAB7C5D-B075-400F-9B48-5FF227E02183 */
        Status = 'NA' ,
        StatusDate = GETDATE()
WHERE Msisdn = @Msisdn

    COMMIT

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF XACT_STATE() <> 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

    DECLARE @errormessage varchar(max)
    SELECT  @errormessage=ERROR_MESSAGE()
    RAISERROR(@errormessage, 16, 1)
END CATCH
END
```

I call this procedure in java like that (CALL_UPDATE_MNO_MSISDN_STATUS = UpdateMnoMsisdnStatus) :

```
 public int updateMnoMsisdnStatus(String msisdn, String mnoRef, String newStatus){

    LOG.info("updateMnoMsisdnStatus with:\n msisdn: {}\n mnoRef: {}\n status: {}", msisdn, mnoRef, newStatus);
    StoredProcedureQuery sp = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery(CALL_UPDATE_MNO_MSISDN_STATUS)
            .registerStoredProcedureParameter(MSISDN, String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
            .registerStoredProcedureParameter(MNO_REF, String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
            .registerStoredProcedureParameter(STATUS, String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
            .setParameter(MSISDN, msisdn)
            .setParameter(MNO_REF, mnoRef)
            .setParameter(STATUS, newStatus);
    int updated = sp.executeUpdate();

    LOG.info("Updated {} Msisdn to status {}", updated, newStatus);

    return updated;
}
```

When i run this procedure via SQL Server Management Studio, it works well. But
when i run it via Rest service, it plants at this level and nothing returned `int updated = sp.executeUpdate();`

Any ideas ?

Comment: what do you mean by it returns nothing, it will return 0, -1 as this is `int` type. Are you sure you are not getting any exception ?

Comment: i means it plants when `executeUpdate` ! i don't see this log `LOG.info("Updated {} Msisdn to status {}", updated, newStatus);`

Comment: what is `LOG` ??

Comment: `private static final Logger LOG = getLogger(MyClass.class);` Even when i debug it, it plants and nothing doing !

Comment: if you don't the log, which means, that line was not executed and that means there would be some exception. Please check your application and server log

Comment: why not put a try catch around the  int updated = sp.executeUpdate(); line and LOG.error the exception?!

Comment: i have this exception in my log server `/resource-rs/resources/msisdn/%2B32454121007/mno/TSL-OBE/status/Assigned: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.ejb.EJBException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
`